# Ресайз img в div

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Есть блок div, который изменяется адаптивно под разные размеры экранов. Как сделать так, чтобы изображение, которое находится в нём изменяло свои размеры адаптивно и всегда было на полную ширину и высоту, но пропорционально. Делаю копипаст с сайта wix (https://www.pasxcel.com) чекните как на разных устройствах. Так-то изи, но не шарю в JS.

Я вставил свой код, который отображает как будет меняться контейнер. Мне лишь нужно чтобы изображение всегда было пропорциональным и занимало всю площадь контейнера. Например, если я смотрю с телефона, то изображение урезается по бокам и становится по всей длине контейнера, а он квадратный на мобильных, если же с компьютера, то контейнер прямоугольный и изображение обрезается сверху и снизу, но всё также занимает всю площадь контейнера.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.img-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(20em + 15vw);
  overflow: hidden;
}
.img-container img {
  display: block;
  margin: -15% 0 0 0;
}
.img-overlay{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #000;
    opacity: .51;
  }
```

```html
<div class="img-container">
        <div class="img-overlay"></div>
       <img src="img/img1.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то то что вы хотите делается очень просто: вам достаточно указать в стилях изображения `width: 100%;` и всё.

Посмотрите, как это можно реализовать на практике:

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.img-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}

.img-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #000;
    opacity: 0.51;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-container">
    <div class="img-overlay"></div>
    <img src="https://placehold.it/1903x650">
</div>
```

Сохранение пропорций, браузер по умолчанию берёт на себя, если вы, конечно, не переопределяется где-то размеры абсолютными значениями.

Если же такой вариант не подходит и вам нужно, чтоб изображение адаптивно обрезалось (простите, но формулировка вопроса не очевидна), то попробуйте сделать так:

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.img-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(20em + 15vw);
}

.img-backgroung {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url("https://placehold.it/1903x650") center no-repeat;
}

.img-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #000;
    opacity: 0.51;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-container">
    <div class="img-overlay"></div>
    <div class="img-backgroung"></div>
</div>
```

Браузер, опять-таки, сделает всё за вас.

Удачи!

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.img-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(20em + 15vw);
  overflow: hidden;
}
.img-container img {
  display: block;
  margin: -15% 0 0 0;
}
.img-overlay{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #000;
    opacity: .51;
  }
```

```html
<div class="img-container">
        <div class="img-overlay"></div>
       <img src="img/img1.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.img-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(20em + 15vw);
  overflow: hidden;
}
.img-container img {
  display: block;
  margin: -15% 0 0 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.img-overlay{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #000;
    opacity: .51;
  }
```

```html
<div class="img-container">
        <div class="img-overlay"></div>
       <img src="img/img1.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
```

Comment: Хорошо было бы добавить пояснений, что вы сделали и зачем.

Comment: вот и всё для .img-container img width: 100%; height: 100%;

Comment: Но изображение при этом не пропорционально...

Comment: Eсли  пропорционально для img  height: auto;

Comment: .img-container img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

Comment: Вы точно разбираетесь? Тогда изображение не по всей ширине контейнера

Comment: по всей ширине контейнера!  Вы так же написали на верху вопрос

Comment: какой размер вам нужно

Comment: Хорошо бы объяснения в ответ вставить) @ArtemGrishin как вы себе представляете пропорциональное отображение картинки в контейнере с отличными пропорциями? Как вы вставить картинку 2х1 в контейнер 1х1? В частном случае, как вписать прямоуголник в квадрат?

Comment: Смотрите на сайте, я его оставил, там можно посмотреть наглядно. Картинка может урезать ширину и высоту, но самое главное чтобы она оставалась по центру и по размеру контейнера.

Comment: @ArtemGrishin все необходмое для вопроса должно содержаться в вопросе, а не вести на посторонние сайты. Пожалуйста, добавьте в вопрос код, который бы воспроизводил проблему.

Comment: @ArtemGrishin если вы урезаете ширину и высоту, то пропорции картинки меняются, не так ли?

Comment: Я не смогу добавить код с WIX сайта. Я вставил свой код, который отображает как будет меняться контейнер. Мне лишь нужно чтобы изображение всегда было пропорциональным и занимало всю площадь контейнера. Например, если я смотрю с телефона, то изображение урезается по бокам и становится по всей длине контейнера, а он квадратный на мобильных, если же с компьютера, то контейнер прямоугольный и изображение обрезается сверху и снизу, но всё также занимает всю площадь контейнера.